# How to validade if a Groovy file is with correct syntax without running it?

Tags: groovy, command-line

I'd like to run a shell script that would tell me if a Groovy file is syntactically correct *without executing it*. The code wouldn't be run, just validated.

I see that there are similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116233/how-to-check-groovy-script-for-compilation-errors), but I would like a simple command line command. I thought there would be parameter for the compiler, but couldn't find it.

Comment: groovyc MyScript.groovy

Comment: @daggett I tried to clarify the question. I don't want to execute it.

Comment: Why would the compiler execute it?

Comment: @neves,  `groovyc` is a compiler for groovy scripts/classes. it will create `MyScript.class` file if compilation was successful.

Comment: @daggett the problem is that it import other libraries that arent configured in the class path. So it fails always

Comment: @neves, you can add the classpath `groovyc -cp lib/* MyScript.groovy` or maybe you want to do this syntax check at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't manage to get a direct answer. My problem was that I was making a Jenkins pipeline script and I'd like to verify it before commit and push. This was I would get simples errors in less time.

I've solved my problem using a [VSCode Extension](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/11/07/Validate-Jenkinsfile/) to validate the file *before* committing. No more typos in committed in my version control.